# UIBarButtonItem action selector working for iPad but not for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uibarbuttonitem

Following code adds a UIBarButtonItem to my navigation controller. When I click the bar button on the iPad Simulator the selector buyApp does get called however the same selector buyApp does not get called on the iPhone simulator.

```
UIBarButtonItem *buyButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
buyButton.title = NSLocalizedString(@"BUY", nil);
[buyButton setTarget:self];
[buyButton setAction:@selector(buyApp:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buyButton;
```

UPDATE: I am using xib for UI and am pushing it's viewcontroller on the the navigation controller.

Comment: Its working fine to me..

Comment: I tried you code, and it worked fine in both simulators. You should provide a little more information on how your app is set up. Are you using storyboards, xibs, or doing it all in code? What does the code in your app delegate look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"BUY" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(buyApp)] autorelease];
```

Better to try this for decrease the code lines

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found what the problem was. There is nothing wrong with the code.

The problem was with testing. The way I was trying to verify the functionality was by printing a string using NSLog. However while testing using the simulator, I switched between the simulators using Hardware -> Device -> iPhone and I could not see the NSLog output.

Once I explicitly stopped the iPad simulator and restarted the app in the iPhone simulator I could get the NSLog output. Weird simulator behavior.